# WSO2 Identity Server Migration Status

Tags: wso2, migration, upgrade, wso2-identity-server

What is the absolute way of knowing that the migration has been carried out successfully?

I'm upgrading WSO2IS from 5.3.0 to 5.7.0 following the Migration guide of each version. I'm checking the About page where the version is displayed and the new features released in order to confirm the migration is done.

A freshly downloaded 5.4.0 shows version in about page on running the product, whereas freshly downloaded 5.5.0 doesn't.

While upgrading from 5.3.0 to 5.4.0, the version was displayed in the about page and I proceeded with next version. After migrating to 5.5.0, the version is not getting displayed in the about page and I assume because a fresh download didn't show either.

Documentation doesn't provide any information on verifying the migration status once it has been run.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the code](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/blob/master/modules/migration/migration-service/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/is/migration/MigrationClientImpl.java#L89), you should get the following log after a successfull migration.

> INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} -   WSO2
>   Product Migration Service Task : Execution was done through all the
>   requested version list without having unexpected issues. There may be
>   some steps that is not executed correctly but bypass that because of
>   enabling 'continueOnError' property. Please see the above logs to more
>   details.

Also, note that you don't have to migrate step by step. It is a seamless migration. You can refer more from [the official documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Upgrading+From+an+Older+Version+of+WSO2+IS).

Comment: I can see this log more than once in the log file. Is the log entered after each component is migrated? What of all the steps bypassed because of enabling 'continueOnError' property? How does it affect the server?

Comment: @sajith, could you clarify your statement: "Also, note that you don't have to migrate step by step. It is a seamless migration" please

Comment: @JavaMastaRSA, you can configure the starting version and target version in migration-config.yaml, then run the migration. It migrates in one go.
Eg: `currentVersion: "5.3.0"
migrateVersion: "5.7.0"`

Comment: @Ramya259 No, It prints only once. The reason for getting this multiple times could be you have run the migration multiple times. In that case, you can restore the previous database and run the migration again.

Comment: @Ramya259 if enable `continueOnError`, it will not stop the migration process when an error occurs (but it will log the error) and continue to the next step. Later, you have to manaually review the logs and findout what was the issue.

Comment: @Sajith Got it. The issue exists and must be resolved later. Thanks!

Comment: @Sajith, while upgrading from older to latest version directly, wouldn't the configuration changes be cumbersome if migration is done from 5.3.0 to 5.7.0?

Comment: @Sajith, what does it mean when we get this error 'Migration process was stopped' even if `continueOnError` is set to `true`?